# Why has this erb behavior changed in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm porting a Rails 2.8 application to Rails 3. Most things are now working, and am slowly ironing out kinks. One behavior that I've found is kind of perplexing, and I would like to understand what changed behind the scenes. The following code snippet works in 2.x, but fails in 3.0:

```
<% if @apps.nil? || @apps.empty? %>
  No rated applications.
<% else 
  ratingshidden = false
    @apps.each { |app| %>
 display app stuff etc....
```

to make it work in 3, I have to change as following:

```
<% if @apps.nil? || @apps.empty? %>
  No rated applications.
<% else %>
<%
  ratingshidden = false
    @apps.each { |app| %>
 display app stuff etc....
```

What changed in rails to require this updated syntax?

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `@apps.blank?` instead of `@apps.nil? || @apps.empty?`. Docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank%3F).

Comment: Thanks, I've been using that for strings, not sure why I didn't use it here!

Comment: This looks possibly related to the deprecation of style block helpers... would love to know more about the internal changes. Starting a bounty....

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3) railscast explains the changes in erb blocks in Rails 3 and why they were made.

Comment: Hmm... good railscast but doesn't quite shine light on the instance shown here

Comment: You're right, I watched it again just now. I wonder if it has to do with whitespace significance. Is there documentation for ERB that gives this as expected behavior?